# Jquery Mobile Autocomplete with Ajax and Knockout JS is not Updating Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to update some radio buttons with knockout js. I retrieve the data from an ajax call similar to this [example](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/#&ui-state=dialog). Everything works well so far. Data is retrieved and passed to the model. And even the List is generated.

[image]

The problem is that jquery is not "skining" the radio list. (Upper part on the image)
Working with a parsed JSON-String everything works fine. (Lower part on the image)

Any ideas?

Thanks

**Code:**

HTML

```
   <fieldset id="myList" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="foreach: myVals">
           <label data-bind="text:$data, attr: { for:'vals'+$data}"></label>
           <input type="radio" data-bind="checked:$root.selectedVals, value:$data ,attr: {name: 'list', id:'vals'+$data}" >
   </fieldset>...
```

JavaScript

> ```
>             // Knockout
>             function viewModel() {
>                 self = this;
>                 self.myVals = ko.observableArray();
>                 self.selectedVals = ko.observable();
>             }
>             var vm = new viewModel();
>             ko.applyBindings(vm);
>
>             // Jquery
>             $(document).on("pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
>                 $("#autocomplete").on("filterablebeforefilter", function(e, data) {
>
>                     var $input = $(data.input), value = $input.val();
>
>                     if (value && value.length > 2) {
>
>                         $.ajax({
>                           ... get data
>                         })
>                                 .then(function(response) {
>                                     vm.myVals.removeAll(); // clear so results won't add 
>                                     $.each(response, function(i, val) {
>                                         vm.myVals.push(val); // fill Array
>
>                                     });
>
>                                 });
>                     }
>                 });
>             });
> ...
> ```

Comment: you need to enhance dynamically created radio buttons using `$("ul [type=radio]").checkboxradio();` this should be added to data binding function.

Comment: You mean by creating a custom binding in knockout?

Comment: yup, it should go within KO function.